Finding the area of trapezoid in a quadrant

A quadrant of radius $6$ is given as follows.
If $\text{CD}= \text{DE}= \text{EB}$ (i,e. the point $\text{D},\text{E}$ trisects an arc $\overset{\huge\frown}{\text{BC}}$), then find the area of trapezoid $\text{CDEB}$.
I can show that this area equals $9$ using the value of $\sin 15^\circ$, but I may suspect there is a simple way to prove this using basic geometry. Can anyone help this?
I tried to draw square outside and tried to use congruence, but I failed.
EDIT: I tried in two ways.
Method 1 : $\text{BC} = 6 \sqrt{2}$, $\text{DE} = 2 \cdot 6 \cdot \sin{15^\circ} = 3(\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2})$, and the height of trapezoid is $ 6 \cos {15^\circ} - 3 \sqrt{2} = \dfrac{3}{2} \cdot (\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2})$, and direct calculation yields the area of the trapezoid equals $9$.
Method 2: we can get the area of the trapezoid as follows.
$$\text{(area of the quadrant)} - (\triangle \text{ABC}) - 3 \cdot \text{(circle segment $\text{CD}$)} = 9\pi - 18 - 3 \cdot (3\pi-9) = 9.$$
Now I am seeking a way to get the area of the trapezoid by equiareal transformation.

Can you show your approach, so that we can see how complicated it is and determine if there s a simpler way? EG What do you consider "using basic geometry"?

Thanks for editing that in! Your 2 methods are reasonably short already. Your method 2 is what I call "composite figures" to see how linear sums of known quantities can yield the desired area.

A piece of trivia you might know is that for a regular 12-gon with radius $r$, its area is $3r^2$. This is arguably worth committing to memory because it is a neat approximation to the circle's area, using $\pi\approx3$.
But here is a visual proof without getting into trigonometry:

You can prove that the triangles break down the way that the diagram suggests just by tracking angles and acknowledging the isosceles triangles. The squares are each of side length $r$, so you start (and end) with $3r^2$ of area.
So the area of the upper right quadrant of that regular dodecagon is $\frac{3r^2}{4}$. In your case with $r=6$, that makes $27$.
Now subtract the area of your large 45-45-90 triangle, which is $\frac12(6^2)=18$. And that leaves $9$ for your trapezoid's area.
